# Does fog produce right-handed or left-handed circularly polarized light?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, polarization

I have read that when unpolarized light travels through the water droplets in fog, it becomes circularly polarized, but is this polarization right-handed, left-handed, or both? And what would determine the handedness of the circular polarization in this case?

---

These are the articles where I read about fog creating circularly polarized light:

1. **Polarization Imaging: Seeing Through the Fog of War**, By Robert P. White, Ph.D.

https://www.wpafb.af.mil/News/Article-Display/Article/399646/polarization-imaging-seeing-through-the-fog-of-war/

2. **Camera Filter Cuts Through Fog, Camouflage**, by nbcnews

https://www.nbcnews.com/id/wbna46299931

---

[image: circular polarizer]

This is an example of a circular polarizer.

According to Wikipedia:

> Circular polarizers can also be used to selectively absorb or pass right-handed or left-handed circularly polarized light... A given polarizer which creates one of the two polarizations of light will pass that same polarization of light when that light is sent through it in the other direction. In contrast it will block light of the opposite polarization.

---

The reason I'm trying to find out if fog generates left-handed or right-handed circularly polarized light is the following:

Using a circular polarizer, you can absorb either left-handed or right-handed circularly polarized light, bot not both types simultaneously. I am trying to find out whether fog creates left-handed or right-handed circularly polarized light or both because if, for instance, it turns out to be right handed, then you could block it using a quarter wave plate and a linear polarizer specifically configured to block right handed circularly polarized light; but if fog instead generates both right and left handed circularly polarized light then the quarter wave plate and linear polarizer combination would only be blocking half of the light being refracted by the fog.

---

The practical application of this would be a camera filter or eye-wear that could cut through fog by reducing the amount of reflected/refracted light reaching our eye, or the inside of a camera, from the fog.

So I would like to know, does fog produce right-handed, left-handed or both kinds of circularly polarized light simultaneously?

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is not implausible, but it requires special conditions. Generally speaking, creating circularly polarized light requires some form of symmetry breaking. So it is essential that you point us to the source that contains this claim in order for us to have enough context to answer the question.

Comment: I don't know if this is the OP's source, but I did find this: https://opg.optica.org/ao/abstract.cfm?uri=ao-57-19-5464. From the abstract: "We present simulation results quantitatively showing that circularly polarized light persists in transmission through several real-world and model fog environments better than linearly polarized light over broad wavelength ranges from the visible through the infrared." I don't claim to understand it, but according to the abstract the preference for circular polarization has something to do with scattering from large particles present in the fog.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the link. I had actually found that same article previously, but I believe it is about actually shining circularly polarized light through fog because it can penetrate further through it than other types of light. What I wanted to know was if and how does unpolarized light become converted by the fog into circularly polarized light, and whether the light that is produced is right and left handed.

Comment: Related by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/742254/what-happens-to-circularly-polarized-light-when-it-hits-a-linear-polarizer

Comment: I've been reading on the subject lately and it is really embarrassing how little and mostly clueless information I've come across. My initial idea was to see if polarized light penetrates fog better, which is what Andrew's excerpt claims. I'd say combine both approaches - both reduce glare as you suggest, and improve penetration. Blessings